# PHP - Global Variables

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to dynamically set database connection credentials based on who logs into a web page. I'm pretty sure it's not working because of the `$connectdb` variable not being defined. Can someone please check out my code and try to get it working?  Thanks!

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$connectdb="";
class Main extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        echo $connectdb;
        $this->load->database($connectdb);
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($_POST["username"] == "root") {
            global $connectdb="default";
        }

        if ($_POST["username"] == "user1") {
            global $connectdb="user1";
        }

        if ($_POST["username"] == "user2") {
            global $connectdb="user2";
        }

        $connect = @mysql_connect("localhost", $_POST["username"],      $_POST["password"]);//won't display the warning if any.
        if (!$connect) {
            echo 'Server error. Please try again sometime. CON';
        } else {
            print("<a href=\"http://v-admindb/ci/index.php /main/employees?username=".$_POST["username"]."\">Employees</a>");
            echo "<br>";
            print("<a href=\"http://v-admindb/ci/index.php/main/visitors?username=".$_POST["username"]."\">Visitors</a>");
        }//Just an example to ensure that we get into the function
    // LOAD LIBRARIES
    }

    public function employees() {
        $this->grocery_crud->set_table('employees');
        $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();
        $this->_example_output($output);
    }

    public function visitors() {
        $this->grocery_crud->set_table('visitors');
        $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();
        $this->_example_output($output);
    }

    function _example_output($output = null) {
        $this->load->view('our_template.php',$output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of **[THE MANUAL](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)** will show you it's pretty easy to have multiple database connections. You define the connection parameters in your `database.php` config file then call the database with the group name.

```
if($user == 'someguise'){
    $this->load->database('guiseDB');
}
```

HTH

Comment: That won't work unfortunately.  What I need to do is set a variable called $connectdb based on the username from the login screen (using $_POST["username"] ) then use $this->load->database($connectdb)  I tried listing multiple if statements inside the constructor but it did not work.

Comment: I see now in your code you might be using [grocery crud](http://www.grocerycrud.com). I went ahead and took the 8 seconds to search [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=grocery+crud+multiple+databases) for you: http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/420-answered-can-i-switch-databases/

Answer (score 1):

For something as important as this i would **strongly suggest running the form input through CI form validation first**. You really should be validating and doing things like limit the number of characters, make sure its letters only, trim whitespace and XSS cleaning - all before you do anything else. (this helps your user as well)

then to get the value from the form - do something like this

```
$username = $this->input->post( 'username', TRUE ) ;
```

and work with the one variable $username. the TRUE XSS cleans the value, and then instead of repeating

```
$_POST["username"] ==
```

over and over and over, you are just checking $username. also makes the code easier to read. if you need $username in different methods just use:

```
$this->username = $this->input->post( 'username', TRUE ) ;
```

and then $this->username will work in any method in the class.

finally consider having a table of users or config list  -- and then use a different value  to call your database. in other words maybe they log in with the user name: "root" but then its a different name like global $connectdb = "rootadmin"